# PYTHON: Logistic Regression p values

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I am able to print the p-values of my regression but I would like my output to have the X2 value as the key and the p-value next to it.

I want the output to look like this:

```
attr1_1: 3.73178531e-01
sinc1_1: 4.97942222e-06
```

the code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from scipy import stats
    
        
X2 = dating[['attr1_1', 'sinc1_1', 'intel1_1', 'fun1_1', 'amb1_1', 'shar1_1', 'attr_o','sinc_o','intel_o','fun_o','amb_o','shar_o','age', 'race',]]
y = dating['match']
        
dating_log_model = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')
dating_log_model.fit(X2,y)
dating_log_model.score(X2,y)


# getting the p-values 

from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2

scores, pvalues = chi2(X2, y)

print(pvalues)


# current output

[3.73178531e-01 4.97942222e-06 3.49411284e-02 1.14925100e-11
 6.40544454e-02 7.46131800e-10 3.52640714e-58 1.31669842e-17
 5.15620104e-15 1.42543106e-62 6.60005884e-15 1.52260795e-81
 7.41356400e-02 8.19087227e-01]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead of directly print the `pvalues`

```
com_dic = {'X2':X2.columns, 'pvalues':pvalues}
result = pd.DataFrame(com_dic)
print(result)
```